# Draw red X over an external image using PGF/Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to draw a thick red X over an image from a PNG file, as a part of a Tikz picture.  How can this be done?  The documentation regarding external images in PGF is a bit vague.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture or this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place the image in a node and use the node anchors to draw the cross

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (img) {\includegraphics{foo.png}};
  \draw[red, line width=1mm] 
    (img.south west) -- (img.north east)
    (img.south east) -- (img.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do the same using \pgfuseimage, but apparently it does not get the bounding box right.

Comment: You can modify the extend to which the lines are going beyond the image using either the `inner sep` or `outer sep` option for the image `\node`. For example: `inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt` will make the cross exactly the size of the image.