# How can I write text to a graphic?

Tags: graphics, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture)

I want to write text to a graphic. Firstly I thought about the `wallpaper` package in combination with the `textpos` package. Do you know a better opportunity for me?

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz