# How do I label parts of an image?

Tags: diagrams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture)

Take this image for example:

[image]

How can I add labels to an image as done above without manually drawing a line and adding text at the end of the line?

Comment: Please have a look at the package `overpic`.

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture.

Comment: You should not miss [one of the star questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/3235) of TeX.SX.

Comment: @Marco: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/overlay#overpic The example with the tiger is the result I want, but I still have to manually draw the lines. Do you have something more specific I can look up than just overpic?

Comment: @howardh: What do you mean with `have to manually draw the lines`?

Comment: May be useful? http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try the following. In the code, the file `can` is your image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (5,5) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{can}};

%to help place things, draw a grid
%remove grid when done
\draw (0,0) grid (10,10);

\draw (5,5) -- ++(4,0) node[above=5pt,anchor=south east,inner sep=0] {this is a label};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Because your image already has annotations, I use the following image as an example.

[image]

Then I converted it to EPS (named as `grenade.eps`) using ImageMagick.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\ImageBox
\savebox\ImageBox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{grenade}}

\def\Rows{5}
\def\Columns{5}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    subgriddiv=5,
    subgridcolor=lightgray,
    gridcolor=blue,
    subgriddots=10,
    griddots=100,
}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\ImageBox/\Rows,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\ImageBox/\Columns,
    nodesepA=3pt,
    linecolor=red,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-\Columns,0)(\Columns,\Rows)% turn off the grid by setting showgrid=false
\rput[b](0,0){\usebox\ImageBox}
% Pull Ring
\psComment[ref=l,angleA=180](4,3)(1.9,3.5){\large Pull Ring}[\ncdiagg]
% Safety Pin
\psComment[ref=l,angleA=180](4,4.8)(0.95,4.4){\large Safety Pin}[\ncdiagg]
% Body
\psComment[ref=r](-4,4)(0,2){\large Body}[\ncdiagg]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Don't forget to compile the source code either with `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence.

Output without grid is as follows.

[image]

And if you need the grid to find the node coordinates during the development.

[image]

Comment: pstricks-add knows `\psComment*[ref=r]{->}(x,y)(x,y){Label}[\ncdiag]`

Comment: @Herbert: The code has been edited using `\psComment`.

Comment: Will this work only with eps files?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: with `xelatex` you can also use `png`, `pdf`, and `jpg`. In short: every possible image for `latex` _or_  `pdflatex`

Comment: @Herbert Thanks.I am still trying to get familiar with pstricks. No doubt that this is a much superior answer to the TikZ offered above.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I tried to mimic the labels given by the questioner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{12pt}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\ImageBox
\savebox\ImageBox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{grenade.eps}}

\newcommand\Rows{5}
\newcommand\Columns{5}

\newpsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    subgridcolor=green!20,
    subgridwidth=0.05pt,
    gridcolor=cyan!30,
    gridwidth=0.1pt,
    subgriddiv=2,
}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\ImageBox/\Rows\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\ImageBox/\Columns\relax,
    style=gridstyle,
    linecolor=red,
}

\def\mylabel(#1,#2,#3)[#4][#5][#6]{
    \dotnode(#1,#3){#4start}
    \pnode(#2,#3){#4stop}
    \ncline{#4start}{#4stop}
    \rput[#6](#4stop){\large #5}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-\wd\ImageBox,0)(\wd\ImageBox,\ht\ImageBox)
\rput[b](0,0){\usebox\ImageBox}
%\psgrid
% Pull Ring
\mylabel(1.9,4,3.5)[pr][Pull Ring][br]
% Safety Pin
\mylabel(0.95,4,4.4)[sp][Safety Pin][br]
% Body
\mylabel(0,-4,2)[b][Body][bl]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See my other answer on this page. There is an update there. I don't want to update this question to save my time.