# How to label images in Latex

Tags: graphics

[image]

The image has 2 labels (1) and (2) with red arrows
Is it possible to do this in Latex or should I try something else to achieve similar result.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57421/19356) was written to answer your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I think that @Marienplatz's link makes your question look like a duplicate- could you confirm that the answers there resolve the issue? If they don't, and your question is a follow-up, please provide some details. Welcome!

Comment: Or with [my other answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40457/19356). It is more specific to your problem.

Comment: Based on the comments above, I used Tikz to solve this problem.