# How to put text in an existing figure/image (maybe with tikz?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, floats

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)
>   [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20792/86)

I was wondering if it's possible to have an existing image (possibly in a figure environment) and then add text at arbitrary locations within that image/figure. Does maybe Tikz allow something like that?

For clarity: [This wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_synapse) has this synapse image with hyperlinks at the beginning of arrows that point to specific parts of the synapse.
When clicking on the image I only see the png file and the hyperlinks disappeared and only arrows without description pointing to stuff so I would like to reintroduce these texts.

Comment: Take a look at the question [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559) as it seems similar.  Does that help?  If not, it would be useful if you could explain how your situation differs from that.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: As this doesn't say TikZ *must* be used, I've added a link to a question with non-TikZ ways of doing this as well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No doubt you can use TikZ but if you just want to overlay text you don't need any extra packages at all

```
\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(0,0){\includegraphics{....}}
\put(10,10){hello}
\end{picture}
```

will write "hello" over your image.

Comment: What does (100, 100) mean?

Comment: @HaozheXie make an (invisible) box 100pt x 100pt in size, in which the image is placed in bottom left (0,0) and the text placed slightly up and to the right (10,10)

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply.