# Is there a template for making memes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, templates

Memes are trivial to generate online. I was wondering however if there is a simple, elegant template for doing it with Latex. I haven't found anything on this.

I'm thinking on two ways. One is just a standalone image/figure, e.g. with tikz. Another is to program a function where you enter the inputs (image, text, etc). Just to give an example, for a particular image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=center]
    \node  {\includegraphics{photo.jpg}};
    \draw (3.1,-3.5) node[rotate=7] {\huge \textbf{Quake $>$ Counter-Strike}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where "photo.jpp" is the empty one taken from [here](https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Change-My-Mind). This results in:

[image]

So, the questions. **Is there a meme generator around based on Latex?** If not, which is an efficient template to produce one? Maybe you can share one? I made one attempt, but I'm not an expert at all in Latex, let alone Tikz (or alternatives). Naturally, memes vary in size, shape and form, so ideally a general tool would be great, but of course, this is likely to be difficult.

Comment: Do you only want to make this one macro, or what?

Comment: @AzorAhai No. That was just one example. I'm asking in general.

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific meme packages - but there are some related questions like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52544/how-to-put-text-in-an-existing-figure-image-maybe-with-tikz.

Answer (score 8):

It depends a bit on how you define meme but possibly you are looking for the `tikzlings` package. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/dent/.style={code={
\draw (0,2.7) to[out=0,in=180] (1.8,3.1) to[out=0,in=70] (2.9,1)
to[out=-110,in=90] (2.5,-1) to[out=-90,in=0] (1.5,-3.1)
to[out=180,in=0] (0,-0.8) to[out=180,in=0] (-1.5,-3.1) 
to[out=180,in=-90] (-2.5,-1) to[out=90,in=-70] (-2.9,1) to[out=110,in=180] (-1.8,3.1)
to[out=0,in=180] cycle;}}]
\pic[thick,scale=0.2]{dent};
\node[scale=7] at (-2,1) {$=\rho$};
\mouse[shift={(-6,0)},scale=1]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, very interesting use of `tikzlings`!

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do some memes, understand a photo with some message on it typeset with white font and black font border. The code has to be compiled with `lualatex` if you want to use the `Impact` font (available at least on my Win10).

The `firsttime.jpg` image used in the example was obtained [here](https://i.imgflip.com/2nre7u.jpg).

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Package for handling graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Package for loafding system fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Load system impact font, qui common for memes apparently
\setmainfont{Impact}
% Package for font frame coloring
\usepackage{contour}
% Style to ease relative positionning of node w.r.t the image
\tikzset{
    use bounding box relative coordinates/.style={
        shift={(current bounding box.south west)},
        x={(current bounding box.south east)},
        y={(current bounding box.north west)}
    },
}

\begin{document}
% Settings for font contours
% Contour thickness
\contourlength{2pt}
% Resolution of the contour (number of copies of the contour shape)
\contournumber{100}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
    \node[use as bounding box] {
        \includegraphics[
            % Diemnsions to be set if you want to print the meme as a standard photo 10*15 format
            width=15cm,
            height=10cm,
            keepaspectratio
            ]{firsttime.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[use bounding box relative coordinates]
              \node[anchor=south] at (0.5,0.03) {\contour{black}{\fontsize{35}{0} \selectfont \textcolor{white}{First time ?}}};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]