# How to assemble several images and a text in the same figure

Tags: floats, tufte

I want to make a figure that contains 2 images and text as presented in the following figure with two images A and B :

[image]

I work with Overleaf so the two images are in pdf format.

This is where I am (the result is far from what I expect), and I don't understand why the two images are framed with this code:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,afterpage}
\geometry{height=9.8in,width=6.9in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Prelude_1-5_sys1.pdf}}\\
\hfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{Prelude_1-5_sys2.pdf}
\noindent
\textbf{$\xrightarrow{\makebox[0.5cm]{}}$Conséquent sur Pédale de dominante en \textit{la} majeur}
}
\end{document}
```

Who can help me to do this figure ?
Thank you !

Comment: Regarding "I don't understand why the two images are framed with this code": There is a frame around each image because you used `\fbox` around the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to put text in an existing figure/image (maybe with tikz?) (duplicate)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52544/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach using `tabularx` to place image, arrow and text side by side and vertically centered:

[image]

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,afterpage}
\geometry{height=9.8in,width=6.9in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Prelude_1-5_sys1.pdf}\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth,valign=c]{Prelude_1-5_sys2.pdf}
&
$\xrightarrow{\makebox[0.5cm]{}}$
&\textbf{Conséquent sur Pédale de dominante en \textit{la} majeur}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied the pictures from your questions, so the alignment is not perfect, but the code gives you the idea.

```latex
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\geometry{height=9.8in,width=6.9in}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[htp]

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sys1}\\[1ex]
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{sys2}\hfill
\raisebox{18ex}{$\xrightarrow{\hspace{0.5cm}}$}\hfill
\raisebox{18ex}{%
  \small\bfseries
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  Conséquent sur \\ Pédale de dominante \\ en \textit{la} majeur
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the amount of raising until it satisfies you.

[image]