# How can I add or overlay a legend to an .eps image

Tags: graphics, overlays, eps, legend

Assume someone has several Matlab plots saved as .eps graphics and realizes in some of them the legend for the curves is missing.
Is there a way to add these legends afterwards, or to overlay another .eps graphic that contains just the legend box?
The .eps graphics are included like

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{path/to/eps}
    \cprotect\caption{gibberish.}
    \label{fig:fug}
\end{figure}
```

A solution using as little 'non-standard' libraries as possible would be favored.

Comment: see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/overlay

Comment: The `overpic` package may be what you need; see [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture). Don't use `\cprotect` except when it's *really* needed: it isn't in a normal `figure` environment.

Comment: Nice to know and thanks for the link. I really do need `\cprotect` because I have a `\verb||` expression in the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\filename{fist-of-legend}
\def\row{10}
\def\column{10}
\def\scale{1}


\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}
\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\column,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\row,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\column,\row)% set showgrid=false for the final
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \rput(7,1.25){\psscalebox{3}{\bf\color{white}PSTricks}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks:

1. Compile it with either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence (much faster) or `xelatex` (much slower).
2. Toggle the `showgrid` with `true`, `false`, `top`, or `bottom`. `true` is identical to `bottom`. The grid is useful to find the coordinate.

Comment: Or you can read my previous answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57421/19356).