# Chunk of text on the right of a picture

Tags: graphics, r

I have a portion of a latex document that is similar to:

```
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figure/plot} \hfill{}
some text...
\end{knitrout}
```

(it has been generated from R using knitr). It puts the picture I want, and below `some text...`. I want to put `some text...` at the right of the picture. How could I do it?

EDIT: adding the R code to generate the latex code for the picture:

```
<<plot,echo=FALSE,fig.align="left",out.width="0.5\\linewidth">>=
generatePicture()
@
```

Comment: See [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture) and [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz). They might be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find it using `\minipage`. I'm posting what I did if someone has the same problem, or if someone else knows a better way.

```
\minipage[t]{\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\begin{knitrout}
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}

\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{figure/plot} \hfill{}



\end{knitrout}

\endminipage%}
\hfill
\minipage[t]{\dimexpr0.48\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
\vspace{10 mm}
Some text...
\endminipage
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29143/caption-on-the-side-of-a-figure