# Explicitly set citation numbers for some references in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am writing a review paper that discusses a set of core references and additionally cites other supporting references. Since I want to add citation numbers to plots created outside of latex and because the core references are more important, I want to explicitly set their numbers such that they have the smallest numbers starting with 1.

I am looking for a solution similar to the one in the accepted answer in this related thread:
[How to customize bibtex numbering in a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378160/how-to-customize-bibtex-numbering-in-a-document) that works with natbib and does not require manually entering bibliography items.

Other related thread:
[How to fix citation number [IEEE style] for some references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268643/how-to-fix-citation-number-ieee-style-for-some-references)

Additional information:
I use `\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` and work in overleaf.

Answer (score 0):

I just found my own quick and dirty workaround: Add `sort&compress` keyword to natbib `\usepackage[numbers, square, sort&compress]{natbib}` to force references to be numbered in the order of appearance in the text. Then, cite target references at the beginning of the document invisibly, e.g. by using `\phantom{\cite{<refkey1>,<refkey2>,...}}`. This will result in the target references appearing first in the bibliography.

Comment: Instead of `\phantom{\cite{<keys>}}` `\nocite{<keys>}` might be more natural.3