# 3D structure of MOS transistor

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am really nervous to create a 3D image and it's corresponding front view version of the following figure. I got to know from googling that "Asymptote" is good for 3D than Tikz ( I have bit of 2D drawing knowledge in Tikz), but I bit confused in choosing between Tikz and Asymptote. Also am afraid that can I read all new language(Asymptote) for it.
[image]
and it's front view.
[image]

Can Anyone help in choosing which tool to use and a simple explanation with code for generating **curvy shapes** and **patterns**

Comment: Personally, I would go for a software like Microsoft Visio, draw.io, Google Drawings or Dia (the list goes on). Then you can overlay text in LaTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792 for example). In addition, as you already saw in your last question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382988), you should provide "what I tried so far". Otherwise, it's a "do it for me" :).

Comment: The second picture is 2D anyway. You could fake the 3D in the first one easily using Ti*k*Z if you want to. (`tikz-3dplot` may help.) You don't really need 3D for this. If you need real 3D, though, you need to pick suitable software.

Comment: How is this question any different from your earlier one, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382988/how-to-draw-cmos-fabrication-process-in-3d-top-and-side-view? It just posts a different image, but the question is the same and the images seem relevantly equivalent. Rather than posting identical questions with very slightly different images, you should focus on improving your earlier question. In the end, you have to try something and see what you like. It is not a life-shaping decision: you can try something else later.

Comment: I don't need a real 3D graphics for this. I just need to know which tool (Tikz or Asymptote) to use for the 3D version of the structure and also the code to generate the 3D, with some explanation. [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382988/how-to-draw-cmos-fabrication-process-in-3d-top-and-side-view). I know that this link also had the same type of question, but I found that it's so complicated and it might not be possible to do with any of the tool(Tikz or Asymptote).

Answer (score 1):

You have probably solved your problem. However, here I send a suggestion to someone else who needs a similar figure in the future.

```
    
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        Text/.style={font=\normalsize\sffamily,text centered, minimum size=1cm, text width=3cm},
    }
 
    \node[Text] (p-type) at (5.5, .25) {p-type Body};
    \draw (0,0)rectangle (11,3);
    \draw (0,3)--(2, 7)--(13, 7)--(11, 3)--(0,3);
    \draw (11,0)--(11, 3)--(13, 7)--(13, 4)--(11,0);
    
    \draw[fill = gray!50] (4.25,3) -- (1,3) -- (1,2.5) to [out=270,in=180] (1.5,2) -- (3.75,2) to [out=0,in=270] (4.25,2.5) -- (4.25,3);
    \draw[fill = gray!50] (1,3)--(3, 7)--(6.25,7)--(4.25,3)--(1,3);  
    \node[Text] (n1) at (2.625, 2.3) {n+};
         
    \draw[fill = gray!50] (10,3) -- (6.75,3) -- (6.75,2.5) to [out=270,in=180] (7.25,2) -- (9.5,2) to [out=0,in=270] (10,2.5) -- (10,3);
    \draw[fill = gray!50] (6.75,3)--(8.75, 7)--(12,7)--(10,3)--(6.75,3); 
    \node[Text] (n2) at (8.375, 2.3) {n-};
    \draw[<->] (7.5, 3.2)--(9.25,6.8);
    \node[Text] (W) at (8.75, 5) {W};
          
    \draw[<->] (4.28, 2.75)--(6.71,2.75);
    \node[Text] (L) at (5.5, 2.5) {L};
          
    \draw[fill= red!50] (4,3.5) rectangle (7,4.5); 
    \draw[fill = red!50] (7,3.5)--(7, 4.5)--(9,8.5)--(9,7.5)--(7, 3.5);
    \draw[fill = red!50] (4,4.5)--(6, 8.5)--(9,8.5)--(7, 4.5);
    \draw[->] (3.88, 4.2)--(3.88,3.7);
    \node[Text] (L) at (3.6, 3.7) {$t_{ox}$};
    \draw[->] (3.88, 2.3)--(3.88,2.8);
         
    \draw[fill = blue!10] (4,3) rectangle (7,3.5);
    \draw[fill = blue!10] (7,3)--(7, 3.5)--(9,7.5)--(9,7)--(7, 3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: MOSFET transistor]