# How to put matrix in picture environment

Tags: matrices, picture-mode

I want to put matrix in Picture environment. I am trying this way `\put(20,20){\begin{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}}` but it does not work. How can I put matrix in picture environment.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: [How to superimpose LaTeX on a picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20802/124842) should do the job. - So use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
 \put (20,85) {$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$}
\end{overpic}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something as simple as putting the `pmatrix` in math mode via `$` delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{picture}(100,100)
\put(40,40){Hi mom}
\put(20,20){$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$}
\end{picture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]