# linebreak inside \put

Tags: graphics, line-breaking

How can I get a linebreak inside a `\put`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{pictures/baum}
 \put (20,50) {first line text \newline \linebreak[4]

second line text}
\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

When I complie it like that "first line text second line text" is written in one line :(

<sub>I adapted the minimum example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20802/128042</sub>

Comment: For instance a tabular works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image-duck}
 \put (20,50) {\begin{tabular}{l}
 first line text\\ second line text
\end{tabular}}
\end{overpic}
\end{document}`

Comment: Or `parbox`:  `\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[percent]{overpic}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{baum}
  \put (20,50) {\parbox{3cm}{first line text \\
  second line text}}
 \end{overpic}
 \end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `minipage`, with a big enough width, since you're specifying the line breaks.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
 \put (20,50) {\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}first line text\\second line text\end{minipage}}
\end{overpic}

\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
 \put (20,50) {\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}first line text\\second line text\end{minipage}}
\end{overpic}

\bigskip

\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image}
 \put (20,50) {\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}first line text\\second line text\end{minipage}}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

Note that the placement `(20,50)` refers to the reference point of the `minipage`: centered between top and bottom with no optional argument, the baseline of the top line with `[t]` and the baseline of the bottom line with `[b]`.

[image]

You could also do

```latex
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}first line text\\second line text\end{tabular}`
```

or with `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}` or `\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}` to the same effect.

Comment: For the 2nd image there is a fake overlapping of the sequence of numbers from 0 to 100 with the third image. However, my vote remains positive.

Comment: @Sebastiano Oh, that's just that the guide numbers don't take vertical space, so `\bigskip` between the image is not sufficient; the numbers and the grid will disappear anyway in the production version, because they're used just for helping in placement of the objects.

Comment: Always remember that I am a low user even in English language :O)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `tabular`  environment, but the code is shorter with `\eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth,grid,tics=10]{example-image}%{pictures/baum}
 \put (20,50) {\eqparbox{OP}{\sffamily\large\color{red}first line text \\ second line text}}
\end{overpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]