# Add text at a particular location inside a figure?

Tags: floats, captions, labels, subcaption

I want to add text, such as (a), at a particular location, in the `northeast` corner, inside a `figure` with a `subfigure` environment. I am using the `\subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure1}
\caption{}
\label{fig:capa}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure2}
\caption{}
\label{fig:capb}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{(a) My first figure, (b) my second figure.}
\label{fig:caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do that with the `overpic` package or using `tikz`. Unrelated: you shoudl not be using the center` environment to center stuff inside a figure. Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` and remove `\end{center}`. Reason: figure adds space above and below the image, as does the `center` env so `figure`+`center` gives excessive vertical space.

Comment: Related to what @daleif said, you can refer to this question for a quick introduction to `overpic`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture

Comment: Thanks, @daleif, The overpic is a little helpful for placing text inside a single figure. Can you explain if it can be used in the subfigure environment?

Comment: Just use it to replace your includegraphics in your example