# How to position images with overpic in an equation

Tags: graphics, overpic

I need to insert many images inside an equation and to write something over these images. So i tried something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{overpic}[valign=c,scale=0.3]{image}
\put(50,50){$text$}
\end{overpic}
\end{equation}
```

but the image is not align with the equation. It seems the overpic environment doesn't recognize the option "valign=c". Which option should I use? Maybe the answer is obvious but I'm not so good at handling images with latex.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.